# Error script doble select sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

estoy tratando de dibujar este almacén y quisiera que me puedan ayudar, el dibujo completo es un "almacén" completo, las columnas son los "estantes", el cuadro es la "sección" y la "capacidad" son los objetos dentro. Mi idea era hacerlo con un inner join y meter en ese almacén otro select para que así se pueda dibujar pero tengo problemas con eso

```
SELECT
    AM.IdAlmacenMetroil,
    AM.NombreAlmacen,
    EM.IdEstanteAlmacen_Metroil,
    EM.NombreEstante
FROM Almacen_Metroil AM
INNER JOIN EstanteAlmacen_Metroil EM
    ON AM.IdAlmacenMetroil = EM.IdAlmacenMetroil
    WHERE IdEstanteAlmacen_Metroil IN 
        (SELECT
            SM.IdSeccionEstante_Metroil,
            SM.NombreSeccion,
            CM.IdCapacidadSeccion_Metroil,
            CM.NombreCapacidad
            FROM SeccionEstante_Metroil SM
            INNER JOIN CapacidadSeccion_Metroil CM
                ON SM.IdSeccionEstante_Metroil = CM.IdSeccionEstante_Metroil)
```

Mi segundo select esta funcionando normal, solo veo que el problema es el WHERE ya que tengo que traer una columna pero necesito la otra para poder pintarlo como quiero. Ayuda, por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el error es por que en el in tienes mas de un campo, quita los demas campos y solo deja el que te interesa, en este caso creo que seria WHERE IdEstanteAlmacen_Metroil el que comparas ese busca cual es de la otra consulta y agregalo solo ese en el select

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que en la subconsulta solo debe estar seleccionado una columna del mismo tipo, por ejemplo:

**SELECT 1 WHERE 55 IN (SELECT PRECIO,CANTIDAD FROM Producto)**

--Error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

**SELECT 1 WHERE 55 IN (SELECT PRECIO FROM Producto)**

-- 1

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.